# SUM of COUNT on distinct columns in SQL Table / MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to perform a SUM based on multiple distinct counts for specific columns on a SQL table. The issue so far is I can am unable to perform this sum while I thought the synthax would be okay. But it seems not since I constantly get an issue from this query.

```
 select SUM(`s1`.`t1`) from (
select
COUNT(DISTINCT s1_global) from NPS_deploiement_synthese as s1 where hubspot_company_id = 2436352252
union
select
COUNT(DISTINCT s2_global) from NPS_deploiement_synthese as s1 where hubspot_company_id = 2436352252
) as t1;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery at all:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT s1_global) + COUNT(DISTINCT s2_global)
from NPS_deploiement_synthese s
where hubspot_company_id = 2436352252;
```

Your version could conceivably work, but the subquery needs column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the 2 count():

```
select
  COUNT(DISTINCT s1_global) + COUNT(DISTINCT s2_global) 
from NPS_deploiement_synthese as s1 
where hubspot_company_id = 2436352252
```